# Trouble Texturing a cube with glDraw arrays

Tags: python, opengl

I am trying to texture a cube using a gltexcoordpointer and gldrawarrays (I use PyGL for my environment). I can get the cube to display succesfully (though it is shaded white), but I cannot figure out how to apply my texture to the cube. I suspect the problem is somewhere in my "draw_cube()" function.

Is there a way to solve this using openGL 2.x functions (I can only use fixed pipeline functions)?My code is below.

```
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np


def run_scene():
    glutInit()
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH)
    glutCreateWindow("textured cube test")
    glutDisplayFunc(draw_cube)
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    gluPerspective(40, 1, 1, 40)
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    gluLookAt(0, 0, 10,
              0, 0, 0,
              0, 1, 0)
    glPushMatrix()
    glutMainLoop()
    return


def draw_cube():

    """ verticie coordinates """
    verts = np.array([
     [[0, 0, 0],
      [1, 0, 0],
      [1, 1, 0]],

     [[0, 0, 0],
      [1, 1, 0],
      [0, 1, 0]],

     [[0, 0, 1],
      [1, 0, 1],
      [1, 1, 1]],

     [[0, 0, 1],
      [1, 1, 1],
      [0, 1, 1]],

     [[0, 1, 0],
      [1, 1, 0],
      [0, 1, 1]],

     [[0, 1, 1],
      [1, 1, 1],
      [1, 1, 0]],

     [[0, 0, 0],
      [1, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 1]],

     [[0, 0, 1],
      [1, 0, 1],
      [1, 0, 0]],

     [[1, 0, 0],
      [1, 0, 1],
      [1, 1, 1]],

     [[1, 0, 0],
      [1, 1, 0],
      [1, 1, 1]],

     [[0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 1],
      [0, 1, 1]],

     [[0, 0, 0],
      [0, 1, 0],
      [0, 1, 1]]])    

    """ texture coordinates """
    texCoords = np.array([
    [[0,0],
    [1,0],
    [1,1],
    [0,1]],

    [[0,0],
    [1,0],
    [1,1],
    [0,1]],

    [[0,0],
    [1,0],
    [1,1],
    [0,1]],

    [[0,0],
    [1,0],
    [1,1],
    [0,1]],

    [[0,0],
    [1,0],
    [1,1],
    [0,1]],

    [[0,0],
    [1,0],
    [1,1],
    [0,1]],

    ])

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)


    glPushMatrix()
    texture_id = load_image('podocytes_and_nuclei.tif')

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
    glVertexPointerf(verts)

    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY)
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, texCoords[0]);

    textureID = glGenTextures(1)
    glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID)

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR) 
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, texture_id.shape[0], texture_id.shape[1], 0,GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture_id)


    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, np.product(verts.shape[:-1]))

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY)

    glPopMatrix()
    glutSwapBuffers()
    return

""" code for converting an image into a numpy array """
def load_image( imgpath ):
    img = Image.open( imgpath )
    img.load()
    img_data = np.asarray( img, dtype="ubyte" )
    img_data_RGBA = np.concatenate((img_data, np.full((512, 512,1), 255, dtype="ubyte")), axis=2)
    return img_data_RGBA

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_scene()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable 2D texturing, see [`glEnable`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glEnable.xml):

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
```

Set the minifying filter (`GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER`), see [`glTexParameter`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexParameter.xhtml):

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR) 
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR) 
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)
```

Define the array of texture coordinate attributes like this:

```
 glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, texCoords)
```

or this

```
 glTexCoordPointerf(texCoords)
```

see [`glTexCoordPointers`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glTexCoordPointer.html).

The vertex coordinates are triangles, but the texture coordinate attributes are quads.
Change the texture coordinates. There should be as many texture coordinates attributes as vertex coordinates:

```
texCoords = np.array([
    [[0,0], [1,0], [1,1]], [[0,0], [1,1], [0,1]],
    [[0,0], [1,0], [1,1]], [[0,0], [1,1], [0,1]],
    [[0,0], [1,0], [1,1]], [[0,0], [1,1], [0,1]],
    [[0,0], [1,0], [1,1]], [[0,0], [1,1], [0,1]],
    [[0,0], [1,0], [1,1]], [[0,0], [1,1], [0,1]],
    [[0,0], [1,0], [1,1]], [[0,0], [1,1], [0,1]]
])
```

Further, you have to enable the [depth test](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Depth_Test):

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
```

Comment: Thank you! I was seriously stuck on this issue for three hours.  You helped me out tremendously!